# Rewrite Show/Hide Multiple Divs form JQ to clear JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I wrote script in JQuery but I want to write in clear JS.

I can fix my problem if I m going to use onclick event in HTML code for example:

```js
 var divs = ["Div1", "Div2", "Div3", "Div4"];
    var visibleDivId = null;
    function divVisibility(divId) {
      if(visibleDivId === divId) {
        visibleDivId = null;
      } else {
        visibleDivId = divId;
      }
      hideNonVisibleDivs();
    }
    function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
      var i, divId, div;
      for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divId = divs[i];
        div = document.getElementById(divId);
        if(visibleDivId === divId) {
          div.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          div.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
.buttons a {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.buttons a:hover {
  cursor:pointer; 
  font-s
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
<div class="buttons">
<a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div1');">Div1</a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div2');">Div2</a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div3');">Div3</a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div4');">Div4</a>
</div>
<div class="inner_div">
<div id="Div1">I'm Div One</div>
<div id="Div2" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two</div>
<div id="Div3" style="display: none;">I'm Div Three</div>
<div id="Div4" style="display: none;">I'm Div Four</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But I don't want to mix HTML with JS, and I want to use addEventListener.

My JQ Code below

```js
jQuery(function(){
  $('.targetDiv').hide();
   jQuery('#showall').click(function(){
               jQuery('.targetDiv').toggle();
        });
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){

              jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).toggle();
        });
});
```

```css
.showSingle{
 padding: .9em;
 margin: .2em;
 border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
#showall{
 padding: .9em;
 margin: .2em;
 border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.cnt{
 margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
<a  id="showall">All</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<section class="cnt">
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Content   1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Content   2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Content   3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Content   4</div>
</section>
```

I was trying make problem but every solution was failed, I will very thankful for help

Comment: This is your JQ code that is to fix, right?

Comment: JQ code is ok but I want to rewrite in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, all the HTML event attributes (`onclick`) come out and are replaced by DOM object references that hook up event callbacks with `.addEventListener()`.

Since you have dedicated `<a>` elements in their own parent that show one of a set of dedicated `<div>` elements within their own parent. We can simply use the index of the clicked `<a>` as the index of the `<div>` that needs to be shown.

As for CSS, you should also not use individual styles, but rather just apply or remove a class. This is much simpler and more flexible.

```js
// Get all the <a> elements that will trigger the show/hide code
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons > a.showSingle");

// Convert anchors to a proper Array (so .forEach() and other Array methods work)
var anchorsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(anchors);

// Set up each anchor with a click event handler
anchorsArray.forEach(function(a){
  a.addEventListener("click", showHideDiv);
}); 

// Get reference to the "show all" anchor
var showAll = document.getElementById("showall");

// Set up click event handler for that single anchor
showAll.addEventListener("click", showAllDivs);

// Get all the <div> elements that will need to be shown or hidden
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".inner_div > div[id^='div']");

// Convert divs to proper array (so .forEach() and other Array methods work)
var divArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(divs);

function showHideDiv(evt) {
  // Cancel the link's native click behavior
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();

  // Hide all the divs
  divArray.forEach(function(d){
    // No need to mess with individual style properties. Just apply a pre-existing class
    d.classList.add("hidden");
  });
  
  // Show the div that was clicked using the index of the anchor
  // By removing the "hide" class, the element's style goes back to
  // whatever it was without that class.
  divs[anchorsArray.indexOf(evt.target)].classList.remove("hidden");
}

function showAllDivs(){
  // Show all the divs
  divArray.forEach(function(d){
    // No need to mess with individual style properties. Just apply a pre-existing class
    d.classList.remove("hidden");
  });
}
```

```css
.buttons a {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color:#aaf;
  transition: .5s;
}
.buttons a:hover {
  cursor:pointer; 
  background-color:#66f;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* This class will either be applied or not to take care of the visibility */
.hidden {
  display:none;
}

.showSingle{
 padding: .9em;
 margin: .2em;
 border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
#showall{
 padding: .9em;
 margin: .2em;
 border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.cnt{
 margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a id="showall">All</a>
    <a class="showSingle">Div 1</a>
    <a class="showSingle">Div 2</a>
    <a class="showSingle">Div 3</a>
    <a class="showSingle">Div 4</a>
  </div>

  <section class="cnt">
    <div class="inner_div">
      <div id="div1">I'm Div One</div>
      <div id="div2" class="hidden">I'm Div Two</div>
      <div id="div3" class="hidden">I'm Div Three</div>
      <div id="div4" class="hidden">I'm Div Four</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette If you look at the OP's original CSS code, he didn't complete it, but he did begin writing an instruction about changing the `font-size` on the `a:hover`, so clearly that was an intended effect. I just added a size of my own to make the code's syntax correct. Please read the posts completely before you answer or comment.

Comment: Thx for your answer Scott! That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @EmilBuszyło You're welcome. I added a little more CSS to make your hover effect a little more smooth.

Comment: thanks one more time Scott, it's only one element from my little project. My goal is presentation all of HTML input with validation in html5 and clear JS. 
Scripts above I'll be use to choose show interested for you input (in the form of input checkbox).

Comment: @EmilBuszyło Check boxes would work very similar to what I have here except that you would get those as a group and use their indexes instead of the `a` elements. But then, you'd need to change the `click` event handler (`showHideDiv`) from `classList.remove("hidden");` to `classList.toggle("hidden");` to account for someone wanting to turn off the currently shown div.